# MVC2 To MVC3 Html.Raw(Json.Encode

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a project developed in MVC2 / ASPX / c#.  I updated it to MVC and it works well. Just noticed when I publish it, get propblem with System.Web.Helpers; and copy it manually.

Since the application is very complex I develop additional compenents in new projects.  I used MVC3 ASPX views, in my view I use:

```
var series =  <%= Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Series)) %>;
```

it works great, when I integrate the controller, view and master page in the older application I get this error:

```
The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in System.Web.Helpers, I was using version 2.0; it should be version 1.0.